# Can we tailor down the answer to a specific denomination, when the question merely asks for the interpretation of the verse?

Tags: discussion

I recently answered a question that asked about the interpretation of a specific verse, but did not request a specific denomination. So... I just provided a Catholic opinion based on what St. Thomas Aquinas and St. Augustine said. Is that okay?

Answer (score 3):

The better response is to close the question as primarily opinion based or a Truth Question.

Asking for a verse interpretation is akin to asking for any random person's opinion on any random Christianity topic. We don't do that here.

Comment: What if that "random person" is the Pope?

Comment: @DoubleU Then he's wrong ;)

Comment: And yet we do allow some exegesis questions. Personally I always distinguish between the allowable and the not, but I haven't figured out how to verbalise what I base my decision on.

Comment: @DoubleU: Then it would make for a reasonable answer to a question about Catholicism, but not for one asking for random opinions.

Comment: @curiousdannii: Can you think of an example where we have allowed it?  I'd expect that *most* such questions/answers should not be allowed, so maybe they just flew under the radar somehow.

Comment: There was one time when someone asked a question about how to properly dispose bibles. Many denominations have this response. It was sort of recent, as I participated in it and got the most points. :)

Comment: @DoubleU: I remember [that question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/24065/20). It's not especially recent, and it's probably not a very good example of a well-scoped question. I have actually VtCed.  (I had originally upvoted it when it was originally asked)